# EE3 structure remove index.php

Tags: wygwam, structure, index.php

When adding link "using structure page link type" via backend (wygwam) all links include index.php automatically, is this a bug?

Comment: Under Settings -> URL and Path Settings -> Website index page, is it blank or does it have "index.php" as a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Settings -> URL and Path Settings -> Website index page, it should be blank, by default it will have "index.php", so ensure you delete this.

[image]